# Blank page when served from subfolder in production

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

after creating the project successfully in local i run

```
ember build --environment=production
```

it shows the following message

```
Build successful - 1766ms.
```

I copied all the files inside dist folder to a sub folder in my server
the default route index.php works but no other routes are working. Do i 
need to copy any other folder to server ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to copy anything but the `dist` folder to your server. But if you do not serve your Ember app from the root, you need to tell the router the location:

In `/config/environment.js` add this line to your `production` environment:

`ENV.baseURL = '/subfolder/';`